Using Radio Buttons as Input for Boolean Model Property ASP.NET MVC
I would like to use radio buttons to indicate whether or not something is in need of repair on my form.
I have already referenced this question and used the answer offered by Ben Cull, but I would like the user to have to click on one of the radio buttons in order to be able to submit the form.
In his answer, one of the two options will always be selected because the boolean will always have a true or false value, meaning that you can submit the form without having to actually click on one of the radio button options.
Here is an example of what I have at the moment:
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">In Good Condition</label>
                <br />
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InGoodCondion, "true") Good Condition
                <br />
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.InGoodCondion, "false") Needs Maintenance
            </div>

An example of my model:
        public class Report
        {
            public bool InGoodCondition { get; set; }
        }

It is important that the input remain radio buttons, and require the user to have actually click good condition or bad condition in order to be able to submit the form.

What exactly is the question?

@VDWWD I am trying to make a form input for a boolean model property using radio buttons. This radio button input should be two different buttons that require you to click on one of the radio buttons that indicates true or false in order to submit the form.
